# Dataframe from dictionary where values are lists

Tags: python, pandas

```
dict = {'0': ['hu'],
        '1':['yi'],
        '2':['yu', 'song'],
        '3':['zhou', 'liu', 'wang']}
```

Here is a simple dict, I want to create a dataframe like below format in pandas. because this format helps me to load graph relations in networkx.

```
0 hu
1 yi
2 yuan
2 song
3 zhou
3 liu
3 wang
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are new to pandas, I present you an easier code to read.

1. Since panda's DataFrame object require two lists of the same size like here:

   ```
   d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
   df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
   df
      col1  col2
   0     1     3
   1     2     4
   ```

   We make our lists that are initialy empty:

   ```
   numb_list=[]
   text_list=[]
   ```
2. Then we iterate on your dict, each time the list contains one item, we save both its dict key and its value, and remove it from the same list with pop.

   ```
   for i in dict:
            while (len(dict[i]) >= 1): 
                    numb_list.append(i)
                    text_list.append(dict[i].pop())
   ```
3. Finally, we can use DataFrame object like so:

   ```
   d = {'number': numb_list, 'text': text_list}
   df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can first convert the dictionary to a list of tuples:

```
final_arr=[(x, val) for x,y in d.items() for val in y ] #dict renamed as d
final_arr

[('0', 'hu'),
 ('1', 'yi'),
 ('2', 'yu'),
 ('2', 'song'),
 ('3', 'zhou'),
 ('3', 'liu'),
 ('3', 'wang')]
```

Then use the DataFrame class to make the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(final_arr)
df

    0   1
0   0   hu
1   1   yi
2   2   yu
3   2   song
4   3   zhou
5   3   liu
6   3   wang
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm new in Python & pandas, that really helps a lot!!!

Answer (score 3):

As a word of caution, do not use 'dict' as a variable name. I have renamed to 'd' in this example.

Use:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

or alternative:

```
pd.DataFrame([(k,x) for k, v in d.items() for x in v]).set_index(0)
```

Comment: thanks for the caution, I use it just in my question, thank you for your help.